# Symfony2 issue installing package with composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am using Symfony2 and I am attempting to install this package "troydavisson/phrets" but keep running into this error. Ive never experienced something like this so Im not sure what to do. How do I get around this?

In the "conclusion" it says "Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.1" but I don't even show that its installed. Perhaps Im missing something here.

I am running this command

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar require troydavisson/phrets

Problem 1
- Installation request for troydavisson/phrets ^2.2 -> satisfiable by troydavisson/phrets[2.2].
- Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.1
- Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.1
- troydavisson/phrets 2.2 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle >=4.0,<6.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0, 5.3.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.1, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.2, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.0, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.1, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.2, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.3, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.4, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.5, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.6, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.7, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.8, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.0, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.1, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.2, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.3, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.4, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.1, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.2, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.3, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.1.0, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0, 6.2.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.0, 6.2.1].
- Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.2.1) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.1].
```

Comment: Sometimes it is installed as part of a package. Check your composer.json and/or vendor folder.

Comment: Can you show your composer.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflict between 2 Guzzel versions being used. Composer already have Guzzel installed probably it was required from another PHP lib. This creates problem for the autoloader.

If you focus on the error you can see :

**Can only install one of : guzzlehttp/guzzle**

**troydavisson/phrets** is requiring a specific version of Guzzel. To fix the problem you have to figure out which lib is using Guzzel and if you don't need it remove it or updated it. If this doesn't solve your problem you have to fork troydavisson/phrets update and solve the conflict between versions ( make sure you are using the same ). If it's getting a bit complicated just choose or find another alternative.